# Remove <include view /> from Layout programmatically and free space

Tags: java, android

I got following layout:

```
 <com.htc.idlescreen.base.widget.WorkspaceView android:id="@id/workspace" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.htc.idlescreen.base.widget.IdleViewContainer android:id="@id/background" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/unlockscreen_background" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/unlockbg_below" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <ImageView android:id="@id/unlockbg_upper" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/shortcut_shadowbg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_shadowbg_height" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/shortcut_bg_upper" android:background="@drawable/lockscreen_shadow" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_shadowbg_upper_height" />
        <ImageView android:id="@id/shortcut_bg_below" android:background="#33000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0px" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@id/button_shadowbg" android:background="@drawable/lockscreen_shadow_action" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/button_shadowbg_height" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.ForegroundContainer android:id="@id/foregroundcontainer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.htc.idlescreen.base.widget.IdleViewContainer android:id="@id/plugin" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.MainContain android:id="@id/maincontain" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/shortcut_height" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.HeadBar android:id="@id/headerbar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.ChargeView android:id="@id/chargeview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chargeview_margintop" android:layout_below="@id/headerbar" />
    </com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.ForegroundContainer>
    <include android:id="@id/buttonfooter" layout="@layout/buttonfooter" />
</com.htc.idlescreen.base.widget.WorkspaceView>
```

I wanna remove the view, that is added here:

```
<include android:id="@id/buttonfooter" layout="@layout/buttonfooter" />
```

I tried to just set the visibility to GONE and also removeView(buttonfooter) in the Workspace class.

The view removes fine, but it will still reserve the space and shows a blank field.

Tried to set the layout_height to wrap_content and also call an invalidate().
No sucess yet.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

edit:

buttonfooter.xml

```
    <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ButtonFooter android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.LockIcon android:id="@id/lockiconsphere" android:layout_width="@dimen/lockicon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_height" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
                <ImageView android:id="@id/lock_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/lockicon_margin_left" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            </com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.LockIcon>
            <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ShortcutPanel android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/shortcut_panel" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_panel_height" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <ImageView android:id="@id/shortcut_divider" android:background="@drawable/home_all_apps_div" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_divide_height" />
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/shortcut_panel_padding_left" android:paddingRight="@dimen/shortcut_panel_padding_right" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_height">
                    <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ShortcutSphere android:id="@id/shortcutpanel_shortcut_01" android:layout_width="@dimen/shortcut_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_height" />
                    <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ShortcutSphere android:id="@id/shortcutpanel_shortcut_02" android:layout_width="@dimen/shortcut_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_height" />
                    <View android:layout_width="@dimen/shortcut_center_space" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_height" />
                    <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ShortcutSphere android:id="@id/shortcutpanel_shortcut_03" android:layout_width="@dimen/shortcut_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_height" />
                    <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ShortcutSphere android:id="@id/shortcutpanel_shortcut_04" android:layout_width="@dimen/shortcut_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/shortcut_height" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ShortcutPanel>
            <com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ReminderPanel android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:id="@id/reminder_panel" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </com.htc.idlescreen.base.ui.footer.ButtonFooter>
```

Edit2:

Attempt to hide it: (not original code, at work atm)

```
public class WorkspaceView extends RelativeLayout
    {

        public void init(WorkspaceCtrl paramWorkspaceCtrl)
        {
            mButtonFooter = ((ButtonFooter)findViewById(R.id.buttonfooter));


                            setFooterVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        private void setFooterVisibility(int visibility)
        {
            if(visibility == View.GONE)
            {
                mButtonFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE)

                //this.removeView(mButtonFooter)
                //invalidate();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ever considered removing the line from the XML?

Comment: Using `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` should work. Does `layout/buttonfooter` also happen to have an id defined in it?

Comment: @ Simon. The title says I want to remove it programmatically.

Comment: @ btse, it really doesn't work, tried it already, the view hides, but still occupies the space. The button footer layout doesnt have an id defined.

Comment: @Jan Oh, sorry. Show the contents of `buttonfooter.xml` the `include`-tag basically copies the contents of that XML into the current layout, assigning an `include`-tag an id is probably not the way to go.

Comment: I edited the OP and added the buttonfooter.xml content. In the workspace class (extends relativelayout) i tried to remove the view with View view = findViewById(R.id.buttonfooter); 
removeView(view); ...but no luck. Tried to setvisibility(gone) in the buttonfooter class as well, but doesnt work either. I'm not that familar with java and android yet...coming from the C# corner.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried using [**Hierarchy Viewer**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) or **Dump View Hierarchy** tool in DDMS to poke around and see what is occupying the space? These tools can show you your complete view hierarchy and are invaluable for debugging issues like this.

Comment: Can you post the actual code where you claim you are hiding the view. You could be making some small mistake.

Comment: I added the code in the OP. Can't imagine that theres something wrong? (-:

Comment: @ Alex, thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly I don't have the possibility to run the code through a debugger (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay found the issue :D

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/shortcut_height"
```